# Identifying the memory issue with java application

Tags: java, hibernate, out-of-memory, heap-memory

[image]When I look for a search criteria in Java that is using Hibernate, I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error. This issue only happens in my test environment. I tried to check for my Tomcat setting and found that it is consistent with other environments. I have included screenshot of CPU utilization. I would appreciate if anyone can guide me to resolve this issue.
This is what my my tomcat log looks like

```
threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space] with root cause
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: Most likely Hibernate query returned too many rows. You need to show a heap dump file on crash, CPU graph is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Would recommend enabling JMX in Tomcat in testing only and use Visual VM. This would give you live memory usage samples among many other metrics to help you debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to the limited memory allocated for the tomcat server in the test server. Once I increased the memory allocated for the tomcat server this issue was resolved.